# How to fetch fields a from string

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsrange

resultString is "{lhs: "100 Indian rupees",rhs: "1.8612 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}"

i have a string , in this four fields available .
now how i can fetch second field of this string.
Coz i want to use value = 1.8612 U.S. dollars.
my problem is that my value is in double quotes but the key isn't.
please help me in this parsing.

Comment: look like this string in JSON formate. Use a JSON Parser to get data from it

Answer (score 0):

this seems json. study some json tutorials

EDIT:

here is a link to tutorial

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/

Answer (score 0):

The String you wrote above is a JSON String. You need to parse it and you will get a NSDictionary. You can get the fastest JSON Parser here:

[Nextive JSON Parser](http://blog.nextive.com/392-nextive-json-parser-for-ios-and-mac-os-%E2%80%93-fast/)

Anyways the JSON String, that you have given has some errors into it. The proper string is:

```
{
"lhs":"100 Indian rupees",
"rhs": "1.8612 U.S. dollars",
"error": "",
"icc": true
}
```

And When it'll be parsed it looks like: You'll get 4 keys {lhs,rhs,error,icc} & respective values in NSDictionary.

Hope it works for you.

Edit: If you want to check for a valid JSON String: You can check is

[JSON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/).

This link will let you know where is the error in your JSON String(if error). Else will show you parsed JSON.

Comment: your suggestion is right but i am getting the string from the url like  {lhs: "100 Indian rupees",rhs: "1.8612 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}.
now i want to get value of rhs.

Comment: Please try parsing the string you receive using JSON Parser, that i have mentioned above. I hope it'll be OK.